# Mapping multiple items of an array to a single object / function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Consider the following array:

```
['123', '456', '789', '000', '111', '222', '333', '444', '555']
```

Now, let's say I want to map every 3 items to a function.

That is, `123`, `456`, `789` would get mapped to a `function () { ... }`.

The next `000`, `111` and `222` would get mapped to another `function () { ... }`

I want to do this because I need to execute batch requests to a database, but the maximum amount of IDs I can request is 25 per batch.

So my goal is to map every 25 items to a function (that will execute a batch request) and then execute each function in parallel using `async.parallel`.

The problem is that I cannot use `map` or `async.map` because that would map **each** item on my array. What I intend to do is map each 25 consecutive items to a single object / function.

Is this possible?

I'm looking for any JavaScript or NodeJS solution.

Comment: So do you need something like this? 

array.mapMultiple(arr, 3, function(data){
 // data is an array of three elements
  
        // do your mapped function 
});

Comment: and are the mapped functions different functions? or the same one as in array.map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly related to Node.js but here's a possible solution:

```
var funcs = [a, b, c, ...], // the list of functions
    arr = [], // your data
    items = 25,
    mapOfFuncs = [];

for(var i = 0, len = arr.length, f; i < len; i++){
    f = funcs[Math.floor(i / items)];
    mapOfFuncs.push(f);
}
```

Based on the observation that every 24 consecutive numbers when divided by 25 and floored will yield a certain number equivalent to the corresponding function's index.

It would yield an array `mapOfFuncs` that would have functions that are corresponding to `arr`'s elements. Like, for `arr = ['123', '456', '789', '000', '111', '222', '333', '444', '555']` and `items = 3`, output would be: `[a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c]`

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't what I meant. I want the data on `arr` to get mapped to a `function` object, without executing it. (This solution is actually executing my functions, and I also I have to manually create my functon array)

Comment: @MatiasCicero By "mapped to the function", do you mean passed as an argument to the function?

Comment: No, I mean just like you can map `"abc"` to an object `{ name: "abc" }`, I want `"abc"` to get mapped to a `function` object. `["abc", "def"] -> [function, function]`

Answer (score 0):

more like this?

```
function groupBy(size, arr){
    for(var i=0, out=[]; i<data.length; i+=size)
        out.push( data.slice(i, i+size) )
    return out;
}

var data = ['123', '456', '789', '000', '111', '222', '333', '444', '555']; 

async.parallel(groupBy(3, data).map( part => processData.bind(null, part) ), callback);
//or
async.parallel(groupBy(3, data).map( part => ()=>processData(part) ), callback);
//or
async.map(groupBy(3, data), processData, callback);
```

Answer (score -1):

the javascript function [`splice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) can be used here, to split every 3 (or 25) elements out of the original array.

side-note: be aware that splice modifies the original array.

```
// this removes the first n elements out of the array and returns them
var batch= data.splice(0, length)
```

Here is a complete solution:

```
var data = ['123', '456', '789', '000', '111', '222', '333', '444', '555']
    , length = 3

// this function is called recursively until the whole initial array is processed (and emptied)
function splitTable() {

  var batch= data.splice(0, length)

    // process your batch here (map to the function you want)
    console.log('batch' + batch)


  if (data.length)
    splitTable()
}

// initial call of the function
splitTable()
```

[demo](https://tonicdev.com/mef/569fa42ec1675c0d00a7c909)

Comment: Be aware: `splice` will modify the original array.

Comment: Indeed, I added a notice to the answer.